# Adding new electrical outlet; ceiling insulation is sandwiched between drywall and plywood (attic)

Tags: electrical, drywall, insulation, attic

I'm looking for a good technique to add an outlet to a wall that currently has no electrical. My initial thought until my discovery was to:

1) Identify the stud I want to anchor the outlet to

2) drill up through the ceiling next to the wall and next to where the stud is

3) create a Wire entry through the top plate by drilling back down through the attic (having identified where along the wall I would like to create that hole

4) Feed the wire down

5) Cut a hole in the drywall and install

The plywood top layer is complicating this technique because 1) now I don't necessarily know where the top plate is (though I have a decent guess -- probably where the plywood sheets meet) and 2) I don't quite know if drilling up through the ceiling will work now that I have to run fish tape through two holes 3.5" apart, and separated by insulation.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you not cut out a section of the plywood temporarily?  Alternately, are you ok to cut a hole in the wall to use as access to drill into the top plate?  Also, "old work" boxes don't have to be anchored to a stud, so anywhere between two studs is fine when deciding where to drill for the wire.

Comment: Do you have access to a really long drill bit? I think they're called installer bit or cable bit.

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Cutting out a section of plywood will be a good idea in the future, appreciate the idea. 

Got my hands on an 8” bit and was able to punch through both layers. The wiring is tricky because they’re not using any junctions in the ceiling either. 

I did use the drill to get a read on where the top plate was. Then I punched down through the two layers with a spade bit. The junction for the room was at a GFCI outlet, so I pulled the outlet ran a wire down to it and tapped into it, then routed it up and around to the other side of the room to the new outlet.